# How to set the Application ARN for Amazon push SNS using Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-sns

I am trying to register my Android device to receive push notifications, however the amazon server is returning an error saying it cannot find my PlatformApplicationArn. I am setting it using their sdk but it seems not to be finding it.

This is the error:
AWS Error Message: Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: no value for required parameter

This is the code that sends it:

```
String platformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:897955111111:app/GCM/com.myapp";
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest createPlatformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
String customPushData = "my custom data";
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
platformEndpointRequest.setToken(pushNotificationRegId);
platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(createPlatformEndpointRequest);
```

Comment: Where does the value, 897955111111, come from? Is that your gcm project id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 2 instances `CreatePlatformEndpointRequest` and you're setting the token and applicationArn on one but using the other for your SNSClient request so it's missing the required parameters.

```
String platformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:897955111111:app/GCM/com.myapp";
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);
//probably no need for this
String customPushData = "my custom data";

CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();

platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
platformEndpointRequest.setToken(pushNotificationRegId);
platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);

CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
```

Also, unless your SNS app Region is US_EAST_1, I've found you have to manually set the region or you'll receive a mismatching region error response, so  before calling `createPlatformEndpoint()` set your region like follows:

```
//Replace with whatever region your app is
pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Comment: Just ran into this -- the SDK is not using the documented region determination method @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html#determining-region-from-environment. I created https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/887 .